# Reading a socket

Tags: c, server, ftp

I'm trying to simulate a small ftp server to train myself by accepting connexion from clients and communicate with the good replies and do the tasks asked. But I don't understand why my server always encounter error when reading on the socket to get the client's command. I think it probably is because of getline() but I don't see why it would be

Here's the "accepting" function

```
    static int              my_startserver(char *path, int ssock)
    {
      int                   csock;
      struct sockaddr_in    addr;
      socklen_t             size;

      size = sizeof(&addr);
      printf("Server ready\n");
      while (42)
        {
          if ((csock = accept(ssock, (struct sockaddr*)(&addr), &size)) == -1)
            return (my_error(6, NULL, ssock));
          printf("New connection detected\n");
          if (fork() == 0)
            {
              close(ssock);
              my_newconnexion(my_getdata(csock, path));
            }
          else
            close(csock);
          printf("Waiting for new connexion\n\n");
        }
      return (0);
    }

static t_data   *my_getdata(int fd, char *path)
{
  t_data        *data;

  if (!(data = malloc(sizeof(t_data*))))
    return (NULL);
  else
    {
      if (!(data->fp = fdopen(fd, "r+")))
        {
          write(fd, "540 A stream creation failed.\r\n", 31);
          free(data);
          return (NULL);
        }
      data->fd = fd;
      data->path = path;
    }
  printf("Service ready\n");
  fprintf(data->fp, "220 Service ready for new user.\r\n");
  return (data);
}
```

And here's the function that handle the connexion with a client after a fork

```
void    my_newconnexion(t_data *data)
    {
      char  *line;

      if (!data)
        return;
      line = NULL;
      printf("Waiting for command\n");
      while (getline(&line, NULL, data->fp) > -1)
        {
          printf("Command: %s\n", line);
          if (my_getcommand(data, line, strlen(line) - 2))
            {
              my_treatcommand(data);
              free(data->cmd);
              free(data->par);
            }
          free(line);
          line = NULL;
          printf("Waiting for command\n");
        }
      my_quit(data, -1);
    }
```

Comment: `if (!(data = malloc(sizeof(t_data*))))` -->> `if (!(data = malloc(sizeof *data)))` You were allocating the size of a pointer here. Also: last time I checked, FTP used UDP sockets.

Comment: @wildplasser: As far as I know the [Standard FTP protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_Transfer_Protocol) uses TCP for both kind of channels: control & data.

Comment: @alk Okay. Maybe I was confusing it with tftp, then.

Comment: Oh thanks I haven't notice that error. But it didn't solve the issue it still behave the same way. As for UDP sockets, if you use PF_INET in the socket creation it covers most internet protocol including UDP.

Comment: TCP is TCP and UDP is UDP. On *one* socket you do either one *or* the other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK So I replaced getline() by a home-made function that do the same thing but from the file descriptor (the socket) so I don't have to open a file pointer from it with fdopen to give it to getline and now it works perfectly.

Comment: Please write the code for the solution and not just an explanation in words